# get old item name for renamed files using TFS API

Tags: c#-4.0

My current tfs will be retired in next few months.I am using tfs api to create a parallel tfs on a new server from the existing one. I have folders and solutions that have been renamed. I am iterating items and based on their changetype(add, edit, delete, sourcerename etc), I am checking them in destination tfs.

I am not able to get Old filename for a file, in order to use PendRename when the item that is being iterated is Delete|SourceRename or Rename.

I tried the mentioned solution :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f9c7e7b4-b05f-4d3e-b8ea-cfbd316ef737/how-to-get-previous-path-of-renamedmoved-of-file-using-tfs-api?forum=tfsgeneral

But, my changeset has a lot of changes and hence identifying a particular file seems difficult.

Do we have something that interraltes two items (the deleted and renamed) ones other than the changeset, because there needs to be a uniquely identifier that associated the two items so that they may appear together in TFS history?

Comment: The solution mentioned in your link is not valid. Those guys actually didn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I read this at someplace and modified it for my purpose so that I can get parent branch for a given server item :

ItemSpec itemSpec = new ItemSpec(serverItem, RecursionType.None);

```
        BranchHistoryTreeItem[][] results = sourceTFSHelper.VCS.GetBranchHistory(
            new ItemSpec[] { itemSpec }, VersionSpec.Latest);

        BranchHistoryTreeItem[] thisBranchResults = results[0];

        foreach (BranchHistoryTreeItem treeItem in thisBranchResults)
        {
            BranchRelative requestedItem = FindRequestedItem(treeItem);

            if (requestedItem != null)
            {
                return (requestedItem.BranchFromItem == null) ? null : requestedItem.BranchFromItem.ServerItem;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The support from TFS API can be definitely improved here. For the solution, you will have to look for the associated Delete change instance which is stored in the MergeSources container.

Below I pasted some sample code by which hopefully you will be inspired.

```
var changeInstances = VersionControlSvr.GetChangesForChangeset( 
                                                            %YourChangesetId%,                                                                                
                                                            false,                                                                                
                                                            Int32.MaxValue,                                                                               
                                                            null,                                                                                
                                                            null, 
                                                            true);
foreach (Change changeInstance in changeInstances)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(changeInstance);
    //if (changeInstance.MergeSources != null && changeInstance.MergeSources.Count > 0)
    //{
    //    var source = changeInstance.MergeSources.FirstOrDefault();

    //    Console.WriteLine($"{changeInstance.Item.ServerItem}");
    //    Console.WriteLine("was renamed from:");
    //    Console.WriteLine($"{source.ServerItem}");
    //    Console.WriteLine("::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
    //}
}
```